# Pycharm won't connect tfs

Tags: python, tfs, pycharm

I'm trying to connect TFS plugin to Pycharm 2016.1.2. 
I went to settings - plugins - Intellij task interation for microsoft team found 
then select HTTP Proxy setting. Then select Manua proxy configuration and entered Host name, port as 80 and gave the proxy authentication and select check connection.

It is generating an error Connection failed with HTTP code 401 for http://host:8080/tfs

Does anyone had a success setup for installing and configuring TFS to Pycharm?

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't think this task still works. I have tested by following [article](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7336?pr=dbe) and  download the SDK from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22616 and copy the the directory to lib/. But no Server option in Pycharm. Even tried in IntelliJ IDEA, no luck.
2. Why do you enable HTTP proxy? If to access the Internet PyCharm should use an HTTP proxy, then specify the proxy settings on this page. It's not necessary to use HTTP proxy.
3. Instead of using Intellij task interation for microsoft team foundation server, try [TFS Integration](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4578?pr=). It supports PyCharm Professional Edition. When you install PyCharm Professional Edition, TFS Integration plugin is bundled with PyCharm and enabled by default:

[image]

Check this article for more information: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/using-tfs-integration.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I finished the setup. i used the TFS Integration and the following page is very helpful to set it up. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873092(v=vs.120).aspx